# Value of type '1-dimensional array of Byte' cannot be converted to 'String'

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to open a file from my hard drive, but then to copy that file to My Resources, incase of the file not working on someone else's computer, this is the coding that I am using, which is giving me the above error:

```
Process.Start("C:\Users\jmahone\AppData\Roaming\Local Libraries\Local Documents\Class List.xlsx")
FileCopy("C:\Users\jmahone\AppData\Roaming\Local Libraries\Local Documents\Class List.xlsx", My.Resources.Class_List)
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Value of type '1-dimensional array of Byte' cannot be converted to 'String'
```

If anyone could give me an alternative solution.

Thank You

J Mahone :-)

Comment: You cannot copy a file to your resources, they are embedded inside your EXE and are thus read-only.

Comment: I see now, is there a way for if I go and use the application on someone else's computer, it will be there, and it will not come up with an error to say that the file cannot be found (due to different user)?

Comment: Don't hard-code file paths.  Your code can only run on a machine whose username is jmahone of course.  Use OpenFileDialog.

Answer (score 0):

[FileCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s1c774y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is a leftover function for VB6 compatibility. It was used to copy a source file to a destination file.

It requires two parameters.
The first one is a string containing the name of the source file, the second one is another string with the name of the target destination file (with or without pathname specifier)

In your case the second parameter is not a string, but a reference to block of bytes stored in the resources of your application. Thus you get the error. You need to specify a string containing the destination file name. (Es. "C:\Users\jmahone\documents\MyResources\Class List.xlsx")

If you just want to open the XLSX file, then you need to install it on the user computer on a well know directory like the one listed on the Environment.SpecialFolder enum and then open the file from one of those folders that should exists also on the target machine.

For example:

```
 Dim dataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonAppData)
 Dim myAppDataFolder = Path.Combine(dataFolder, "MyAppData")
 Directory.CreateDirectory(myAppDataFolder)
 Dim myExcelFile = Path.Combine(myAppDataFolder, "Class List.XLSX")

 Process.Start(myExcelFile)
```

See docs on:

[Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: OK thank you, is there a way to copy it to the resources as well as opening it from the source. This is if I go and use the application on someone else's computer, it will come up with an error to say that the file cannot be found, is there any other way around this.

Comment: Do you want to distribute an XLSX file with your application? And let your user edit it and then reinsert it in your app resources?

Comment: No, just to open it Read-Only.

Comment: Thank You for that answer, that is helping.